# Test driven developement for generating (vector) graphics

Tags: image, tdd, vector-graphics

I am starting a [project](https://github.com/aauthor/hexflex) just for fun that deals with simple vector images (e.g. placing small colored or textured triangles in specific locations and orientations).  I want to TDD the project if I can after I get out of prototyping, but I don't really know how to TDD a vector graphic, or any graphic output for that matter.  Right now I'm playing with [RMagick / RVG](https://rmagick.github.io/), but I'm not married to it.

A sample of features that I would like to test:

- a triangle has the correct background (this can come from a simple color, another vector graphic, or possibly (hopefully) raster image)
- has a triangle has been rotated correctly (0-360 degree)
- has a triangle been placed correctly (either in the context of the image or perhaps just in a correct "slot").

I started to look at ways of testing "equality" of a vector image.  The first way that I came up with was to rasterize the vector and compare the vectors.  While this seldom produces an absolute positive/negative match, it does create a good metric to compare the two images.  See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/aauthor/fd13d8267d9fb0193d6a) for what I'm talking about.

Do you think this is a sane way of going about this?  I was also thinking of decoupling my `Triangle` class from the imaging library, so that I could just unit test attributes within the domain of problem that translate into transformations.   Has anyone else here TDDed with image generation that could share some wisdom?

Answer (score 0):

In the ideal world, you would have an interface (thinking C#) that you can then use to create a mock object.  The mock would then be supplied/provided to your triangle/object construction code.  That code would not know it is a mock object or the real RVG.  It should be designed to get an object that is of the interface type, so that when you go into production, the code is the same for either a mock or the RVG.

The tests with the mock should have expectations of what you send it to create/generate a triangle. The decoupling is the approach you want to take. Hope that makes some sense.

Answer (score 0):

In case you can output SVG, you could use XPath to test specific properties while ignoring others. If you had something like

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="30">
  <polygon class="triangle" points="0,0 50,0 25,30" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

then you could test whether the triangle is red with an XPath expression like:

```
//svg:polygon[@class='triangle'][@fill='red']
```

How to evaluate the XPath depends on what XPath libraries are available for the language/platform/... you are using.

Testing more complex properties, e.g. asserting that two shapes don't intersect, is harder.  This specific task could be solved using something like [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/) which has a [`getIntersection()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#getintersections-path) feature.